# Why does wordpress only look at certain child theme pages, but not all of them?

Tags: php

I created a child theme for Twenty Seventeen Wordpress theme and made copies of the parent Twenty Seventeen's header.php, template-parts' header and navigation folders into the child theme.  Wordpress isn't recognizing the child theme's new files. The filepath of one of the files:
[image]

The child theme's style.css and function.php files are acknowledged.  As seen as below (well at least you can see the functions.php):

[image]

I'm trying to edit the child's site-branding file, but the wordpress is still looking at the parent's site-branding file.  Why is this happening? How do I correct it?

Comment: where is the file included? can you post the code?

Comment: the file is included in both the child and parent theme.  I can't post the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming "templates-parts" to "template-parts" in your child theme